# Dynamically named tables in entity framework queries

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, repository

I am thinking about ways to manage a table naming issue for an application I'm planning.

Currently there is a table that contains raw materials (approximately 150 rows) and each row has about 20 columns mainly float-value numbers used for calculations. For reference,  let's refer to this table as 'materials'.

As these number columns are periodically updated and some users may also wish to create custom versions, I will create a management utility that allows copy/edit of this material table but, crucially it will only allow "save as" under a new table name so that data is never destroyed.

Thus using an automated routine, I'll create 'materials_1", "materials_2" and so on.  When a calculation is done in another part of the website, I will store the name of the materials table that was used for the calculation so in future there can be audits done to find where a result has come from.

Now... is it possible for me to do this in an entity framework / unit of work/ repository way (like John Papa's codecamper example) without me having to continually edit the datacontext and add the newly created table names? I can't see how I can pass in a variable to the repository interface that contains the specific table name, which will always be a 'materials' entity even though the physical table name varies?

Comment: I think you are thinking about this wrong. Is there not away to store the data and revisions in a single table rather than spawning new ones?

Comment: Hmm. Maybe. So add a column which is the 'version: like 1,2,3,etc... and then use that in the query. I suppose that even after 1000 revisions there would only be 150,000 rows, which is nothing really...

Comment: I think this is a case for [EAV data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). Some detest it, it has even been called an anti pattern. But sometimes all other options are even worse.

Comment: Read up on EAV data and I think it may be a new model too far for me!  Looks worthy of further research but I don't think it's right for me. Thanks for the input though.